# Osmdroid draw discontinuous path

Tags: android, osmdroid

I want to draw some paths on an OSM MapView. I'm taking the data from a KML file.
I'm drawing each Placemark of the KML as a PathOverlay on the MapView and the result is fine:

[image: PathOverlays]

The problem is that there are too much Paths to draw (over 34.000) and the map is running very very slow when I move or zoom it. To optimize it I tried to draw in the same PathOverlay all the Placemarks that have the same colors as independent lines. There are 8 different colors so at the end I will have only 8 overlays.
But I couldn't find a solution to draw "discontinuous paths" in the same PathOverlay.
I'm using [this PathOverlay class](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/osmdroid-android/src/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/PathOverlay.java?r=885)
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an InvisiblePathOverlay class that extends PathOverlay.  Override the function of the draw method, so that it doesn't actually draw anything on the Map.  You then use that as the interrupted path segments.

Comment: Thanks for your idea, but it didn't work. If I use an extended PathOverlay for invisible lines and normal one to draw them, I have a too much overlays again (over 34.000) and it's still slow. But thanks again for your response :-)